# Configuring Azure Application Gateway to serve Static Website from Azure Storage Container

Tags: azure, single-page-application, azure-application-gateway, azure-storage-account, health-check

I need some help to solve a problem with Azure Application Gateway.

My idea is to serve a SPA from Azure Storage Container so I configured my storage account with Static Website enabled. The backend will be served from a container instance, but for simplicity I'm just routing to a static url (https://www.lipsum.com/).

I want to do something like this:

- When I access **"/"**, I can access my static website
- When I access **"/backend"** I can access my backend API (in this case 'https://www.lipsum.com/')
- When I access any other path, I can access my static website

I configured my application backend pools to point to both urls (my static website and my dummy backend), but my static website is always ***Unhealthy***.
[image: backend health]

If I access **"/backend"** in my AG IP, I'm viewing ipsum site, but if I access **"/"** I'm receiving a ***502 Bad Gateway*** Error.

I will be very grateful if someone can help me to solve this problem

Comment: 502 error in app gateway means that the pool which listening to / is not healthy i.e response code is not between 200-399, so the error seems obvious in your screenshot. You need to fix the 400 error to make the backend pool healthy. Can you try opening the backend pool url directly on browser and see if you get 400 error? If yes, you may investigate why you get that. Also it seems that the scenario you are trying is not supported as mentioned in https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/34977751-is-it-possible-to-expose-azure-blob-storage-via-ap

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the HTTP headers on backend pool for the static website and provide the primary endpoint for the Storage Account in the **Host name** field. [This article](https://medium.com/@emin.askerov/static-website-hosting-in-azure-storage-with-custom-domain-and-ssl-support-using-azure-application-b17f95c6764c) gives you a walkthrough of the steps to set this up and it's covered by [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/configure-web-app-portal) How-to from Microsoft. Although it's configuring a Web Service the principle is the same.

The Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-web-app-overview) explains the concepts involved, again using Web Apps as a example.